# Unexpected error running stored oracle PL/SQL proceedure

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, oracle-call-interface

The database I am accessing has a whole API of stored procedures (several hundred) in several packages.  I working on new client software to interact with this database and I need to invoke these stored procedures using OCI.   Since I am new at this, I decided to start with the easiest one first.  It is not working.

It would be helpful if I could get the actual PL/SQL code of the stored procedure.  The package does not reside in my user schema, but I do have execute privileges on it.  When I query the ALL_SOURCE view I get the package declarations, but not the package body.  I also tried the dbms_metadata.get_ddl view, but it just says "Package PTAPI not found in schema for ".  Are there any other ways to get the actual PL/SQL code from the package body?

Here is the PL/SQL package declaration of the example procedure I am trying to use.  This particular one creates a textual error message given an error code and some optional parameters that depend on the specific error code.

```
-- format an error message from ERRMSGS table
   PROCEDURE formatmessage(
      p_error    IN       errmsgs.error%TYPE   -- index into ERRMSGS
    , p_errnum   OUT      errmsgs.error%TYPE   -- adjusted error number 
    , p_errmsg   OUT      errmsgs.MESSAGE%TYPE -- formatted message 
    , p_a        IN       VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL
    , p_b        IN       VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL
    , p_c        IN       VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL
    , p_d        IN       VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL
    , p_e        IN       VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL
   );   -- formatmessage
```

My code to invoke the procedure is below [statement and err are OCI handles passed into this function from higher up]

```
char errmsg[256]; //buffer to receive the error message
long errnum; //buffer to receive the adjusted error number
memset(errmsg,0,256); errnum = 0; //start the message buffer empty
OCIBind* bind1 = NULL, *bind2 = NULL; //to receive the bind handles
ub4 curelep1 = 1; //1 errnum element
ub4 curelep2 = 1; //1 errmsg element 
ub2 alenp1 = sizeof(long); //errnum element size
ub2 alenp2 = 256; //errmsg element size
char sql[] = "BEGIN PTAPI.FORMATMESSAGE(193,:P_ERRNUM,:P_ERRMSG, '','','','',''); END;\0"
OCIStmtPrepare(statement,err,(text*)sql,strlen(sql),OCI_NTV_SYNTAX, OCI_DEFAULT); //parse the SQL statement
OCIBindByName(statement,&bind1,err,(text*)":P_ERRNUM",-1,&errnum, sizeof(long),SQLT_INT,NULL,&alenp1,NULL,1,&curelep1,OCI_DEFAULT); //bind errnum
OCIBindByName(statement,&bind2,err,(text*)":P_ERRMSG",-1,errmsg,256, SQLT_STR,NULL,&alenp2,NULL,1,&curelep2,OCI_DEFAULT); //bind errmsg
if(OCIStmtExecute(svcctx,statement,err,1,0,NULL,NULL,OCI_DEFAULT) != OCI_SUCCESS) //execute the statement
{
    long errcode;
    char errbuf[512];
    OCIErrorGet (err,1,NULL,(sb4*)&errcode,(OraText*)errbuf,512, OCI_HTYPE_ERROR); //check to see what the error was
    printf("ERROR %d - %s\n",errcode,errbuf);
    return FAIL;
}
```

The statement parses properly and the two binds succeed, but I get an error on execute.   The error I get is

```
ERROR 6550 - ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'FORMATMESSAGE'
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'FORMATMESSAGE'
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
```

I am confused by this error because I imitated a call to this same function from the old client software that works properly.  I definitely have the right number and types of arguments.  Any ideas why I would be getting this error?

**---- UPDATE ----**

I found a better example procedure to test.  This one is not stored in a package, it is a standalone procedure, and so I have the full PL/SQL code.   I get the exact same error.  It has to be something to do with how I am invoking them.   Thanks for any ideas.

This one deletes an item of a certain type from the database (entries on 3 different tables).

Here is the PL/SQL

```
PROCEDURE DELSTL(comp IN 3DCOMPS.COMPID%TYPE,
          rowcount OUT integer,
          errorcode OUT number)
AS
        tempcount   INTEGER;
BEGIN
        errorcode := 0;
        DELETE FROM 3DCOMPS WHERE COMPID = comp;
        tempcount := sql%rowcount;
        IF (sql%rowcount < 1) THEN
          errorcode := 330;
        END IF;
        DELETE FROM IDINF WHERE COMPID = comp;
        IF (sql%rowcount < 1) THEN
            errorcode := 332;
        ELSIF (tempcount < sql%rowcount) THEN
           tempcount := sql%rowcount;
        END IF;
        rowcount := tempcount;
        DELETE FROM ATTLOC WHERE COMPID1 = comp OR COMPID2 = comp;
END;
```

Here is my slightly modified code for this new test procedure

```
long errnum; //buffer to receive the error number
long rowcnt; //buffer to receive the row count
OCIBind* bind1 = NULL, *bind2 = NULL; //to receive the bind handles
ub4 curelep1 = 1; //1 errnum element
ub4 curelep2 = 1; //1 rowcnt element 
ub2 alenp1 = sizeof(long); //errnum element size
ub2 alenp2 = sizeof(long); //rowcnt element size
char sql[] = "BEGIN DELSTL('FAKEIDNUM',:P_ROWCNT,:P_ERRNUM); END;\0"
OCIStmtPrepare(statement,err,(text*)sql,strlen(sql),OCI_NTV_SYNTAX, OCI_DEFAULT); //parse the SQL statement
OCIBindByName(statement,&bind1,err,(text*)":P_ERRNUM",-1,&errnum, sizeof(long),SQLT_INT,NULL,&alenp1,NULL,1,&curelep1,OCI_DEFAULT); //bind errnum
OCIBindByName(statement,&bind2,err,(text*)":P_ROWCNT",-1,&rowcnt, sizeof(long),SQLT_INT,NULL,&alenp2,NULL,1,&curelep2,OCI_DEFAULT); //bind rowcnt
if(OCIStmtExecute(svcctx,statement,err,1,0,NULL,NULL,OCI_DEFAULT) != OCI_SUCCESS) //execute the statement
{
    long errcode;
    char errbuf[512];
    OCIErrorGet (err,1,NULL,(sb4*)&errcode,(OraText*)errbuf,512, OCI_HTYPE_ERROR); //check to see what the error was
    printf("ERROR %d - %s\n",errcode,errbuf);
    return FAIL;
}
```

I use 'FAKEIDNUM' since I obviously dont want to actually delete anything during this test.   Since that doesnt exist in those tables, rowcnt should be 0 and errnum should be 332 when the procedure ends.

I get exactly the same error as with the other procedure.

```
ERROR 6550 - ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'DELSTL'
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'DELSTL'
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
```

Does this give anyone any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: What are the actual data types of the columns in the error table?

Comment: errmsgs.error is type NUMBER and errmsgs.message is type VARCHAR2 with column width 255 chars

Comment: Are you sure the old client and new client are connecting to the same database and same schema - you aren't just seeing a different version of the package than you expect, maybe an old or new copy that's been modified? What do you see if you connect as the same user as your client and describe the package? (Sounds obvious but might as well rule it out...)

Comment: I am connecting to the same database with the same credentials in both cases.   Im 99.999% confident that's not the issue.   In any case see my updates above; I found a better test procedure to use that has full PL/SQL code available.   Thanks for your help Alex!

Answer (score 1):

I got it working.

The problem was in my bind calls.  I changed them as follows;

```
OCIBindByName(statement,&bind1,err,(text*)":P_ERRNUM",-1,&errnum, sizeof(long),SQLT_INT,NULL,***NULL***,NULL,0,***NULL***,OCI_DEFAULT); //bind errnum
OCIBindByName(statement,&bind2,err,(text*)":P_ROWCNT",-1,&rowcnt, sizeof(long),SQLT_INT,NULL,***NULL***,NULL,0,***NULL***,OCI_DEFAULT); //bind rowcnt
```

The parameters changed are curelep, alenp, and maxarr_len.  These parameters have to do with binding ARRAYS.  Since the procedures I am using take single values in/out, I had configured these inputs for an array size of 1.   Evendently an array of items with 1 item in the array is not the same (in oracle's mind) as a single item.   Thus the datatypes for my parameters were wrong because it was an ARRAY of integers and an ARRAY of numbers, and for the first one an ARRAY of varchar(255)'s.

Setting all those parameters to 0 or NULL as applicable fixed the problem.

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need to specify empty parameters, you already have `DEFAULT NULL` for this purpose

So may be that way:

```
char sql[] = "BEGIN PTAPI.FORMATMESSAGE(193,:P_ERRNUM,:P_ERRMSG); END;\0"
```

Comment: Gave it a shot, no change, still same error.   Thanks for the idea though!